# setResult(<resultCode> , <Intent>) does not work

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to pass byteArray and just a String from a current activity to a previous fragment.

```
public void uploadClick (View view) {
    //Send results back to previous screen
    switch (activity.from) {
        case "review" :
            if (activity.mCurrentPhotoPath != null && activity.bytes != null) {
                Intent reviewReturnIntent = new Intent();
                reviewReturnIntent.putExtra(ReviewsFragment.REVIEW_PHOTO_BITMAP, activity.bytes);
                reviewReturnIntent.putExtra(ReviewsFragment.REVIEW_PHOTO_PATH, activity.mCurrentPhotoPath);
                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, reviewReturnIntent);
                activity.finish();
            }
            break;

        case "reply" :
            break;

        case "merchant" :
            break;

    }
}
```

Fragment onActivityResult :

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REVIEW_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                returnedBitmap = data.getByteArrayExtra(REVIEW_PHOTO_BITMAP);
                returnedPhotoPath = data.getStringExtra(REVIEW_PHOTO_PATH);

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(returnedBitmap, 0, returnedBitmap.length);
                binding.reviewIV.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                binding.returnedImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

startActivityForResult call:

```
public void uploadClick (View view) {
    Intent uploadPhotoIntent = new Intent(fragment.getContext(), UploadPhotoActivity.class);
    uploadPhotoIntent.putExtra(UploadPhotoActivity.FROM, "review");
    fragment.startActivityForResult(uploadPhotoIntent, ReviewsFragment.REVIEW_REQUEST);
}
```

Every time I try to run the activity.setResult with an intent parameter. The compiler runs that code, but does not finish the activity (therefore I could not return to the previous fragment / activity).
I've added breakpoints and it runs the "setResult" and the "activity.finish()" methods. But it just doesn't seem to destroy the current activity.

Although, after taking out the intent parameter from the "setResult" method, everything works fine, but on the previous fragment I'm getting a null returned from "data".

Example :

```
activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

Been trying to look for answers around the internet, still no luck.
Would really appreciate it , and thanks for reading. :)

Comment: What is `activity` in `uploadClick()`? Is there any possibility that `activity.finish()` finishes wrong activity?

Comment: Try adding return after `activity.finish()`

Comment: @SergeyGlotov I'm using MVVM, the activity is just referring to the instance of the activity that is tied with the viewModel. (the uploadClick method is in the viewmodel class)

Comment: @DawidJamroży still the same...

Comment: You should not pass activity instance to `ViewModel`. It breaks the whole concept of MVVM. You should send info from your `ViewModel` to your `activity` or `fragment` and call finish in there. By doing it in `ViewModel` there is a lot of things why it may not work in the first place.

Comment: @DawidJamroży ok, will try